# The best pattern to organize my subscriptions in Meteor without the risk to find the data not ready

Tags: meteor, iron-router, subscriptions

I read some of the posts here about how to organize subscriptions in Meteorjs, but I still I don't understand what is the best pattern to avoid finding out some data I subscribed are not ready to be used in a template. I use Iron Router and now I have all my subscriptions organized using a waitOn option in Router.configure. I find out that this way doesn't help sometimes. If I have multiple subscriptions like this:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    waitOn: function () {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('channels'),
            Meteor.subscribe('invitations'),
            Meteor.subscribe('messages')
        ];
    } 
});
```

I understood that order matters. If I change the order of my subscriptions in the array, the program respond differently.
What I want to get is that ALL my subscriptions get completely loaded before navigating the app.
Someone in a previous post talked about putting them in a separate file to solve this problem. But how? Where do I need to put that file?
I would appreciate some examples here for my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the release of `Meteor 1.0.4` the templates instances now have a subscribe method that works exactly like the `Meteor.subscribe`, check [this release](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2015/03/17/meteor-104-mongo-cordova-template-subscriptions) notes to more information about

So you can use that subscriptions inside a onCreated like the follow example.

```
Template.notifications.onCreated(function () {
  this.subscribe("channels");
  this.subscribe("invitations");
  this.subscribe("messages");
});
```

Check [Meteor Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe) about the `subscriptionsReady()`

Comment: Thanks @Ethaan I checked Meteor 1.0.4 documentation and template level subscriptions should be perfect. In my understanding, every template level subscription expires once the template is destroyed. So I suppose that inner templates don't have to subscribe a collection again if the outer templates already did that for them. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes with the template subscriptions its enought

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot to get back here. I'm now using Template level subscriptions and it works perfectly.

Comment: @massimosgrelli if this answer help you could you please accept this one?

Comment: What do you mean by "accept"? I need to have my reputation at 15 – at least – to up vote this answer.

Comment: oh "check" it the green marker is just below the 2 arrows with the up vote reputation,

Comment: Still puzzling over how to use the subscriptionsReady() function in the context of having a template wait until subscriptions are ready for it. Used in iron-router? In the template renderer?  Can you give a simplified example?

Comment: Hi sorry for trouble again after the issue has been closed but after using this on JS file how to show data on HTML file ??